# Split SQL rows into two and properly structure

Tags: javascript, python, sql, c

I have a huge amount of queries large numbers of queries such as:

```js
INSERT INTO `test` (`test_id`, `test_title`, `test_pic`, `test_date`, `test_date`, value) VALUES 
(10, 'Dance0', 'NoPhoto.jpg', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0), 
(11, 'Dance1', 'NoPhoto.jpg', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0), 
(12, 'Dance2', 'NoPhoto.jpg', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0), 
(13, 'Dance3', 'NoPhoto.jpg', '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0)
```

And I would like to split and add the id, and close the parenthesis (**),**) of the queries:

```
(10, 'Dance0', 'NoPhoto.jpg'),
(10, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0),
(11, 'Dance1', 'NoPhoto.jpg'),
(11, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0), 
(12, 'Dance2', 'NoPhoto.jpg'),
(12, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0), 
(13, 'Dance', 'NoPhoto.jpg'),
(13, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', 0),
```

How this could be done? An example/solution to the problem it will be very appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You listed 3 languages, which one are you using?

Comment: After you fetch a row from the query, create two lists/arrays containing the columns you want in each, and append them to your results.

Comment: @Barmar I would like a script solution to this problem eventually, using JS, Python or C

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to restructure the data once it has loaded.  For that:

```
select test_id, test_title, test_pic
from test
union all
select test_id, test_date, value
from test;
```

It is very unclear to me *why* you would want to do this.  The original data seems to be formatted correctly.

EDIT:

If you want to create two tables:

```
create table table1 as
    select test_id, test_title, test_pic
    from test;

create table table2 as
    select test_id, test_date, value
    from test;
```

Comment: I want to split the data into two different tables. Split the data and maintaining the proper ID in the second row.

Comment: @PedroCarvalho . . . You still might find that this is more easily done in the database.  Just use `create table as` instead of `union all` to put the results into tables.

Comment: Can you give me an example?